# is it possible to store product fields and tie them into liquid templeting?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

Is it possible to store fields into variables for individual products to use elsewhere in the code or am I stuck with only API calls?

I'd like to store data for each product into a variables and pass them to the liquid product template to make a dynamic hyperlink for each product.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vPSd.jpg - Example of Embedded App fields to be saved.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxDFT.jpg  - Example of product listing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [metafields](https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/110057030-using-metafields-in-your-shopify-theme) to store and display custom properties of a product.

To save a metafield in your app make a request to the Shopify API:

```
POST /admin/products/#{id}/metafields.json
{
  "metafield": {
    "namespace": "test_app",
    "key": "seller_id",
    "value": 123,
    "value_type": "integer"
  }
}
```

To get `seller_id` in the product template:

```
{{ product.metafields.test_app.seller_id }}
```

Metafields are available automatically in the templates.

Comment: Thanks! I assumed that's what the metafields were used for but didn't know if it was possible to display that data to the customer. Shopify seems fairly strict about what actions you can perform.